# createQuery useage trouble about SQLBrite and SQLdelight

Tags: android, sqlbrite, sqldelight

I use SQLdelight to create sql code,Like

```
SELECT * FROM CoachService WHERE shop_id in (?) and brand_id = ?
```

and I query Like:

```
briteDatabase.createQuery(CoachService.TABLE_NAME, CoachService.GETBYBRANDIDANDSHOPS,  "'1','5','11'","2");
```

but result is empty.
Then,I change sqlcode like

```
SELECT * FROM CoachService WHERE shop_id in ('1','5','11') and brand_id = ?
```

it returns me 3 result.
    Why?

Answer (score 0):

when you pass in a query parameter it gets turned into a string by the android bindings. So when you pass in `"'1','5','11'","2"` it shows up in the query as

`SELECT * FROM CoachService WHERE shop_id in (''1','5','11'') and brand_id = ?`

or something like this, where '1','5','11' is actually one whole string.

Comment: I know what's wrong,but how can I pass parameter ? the shop_id maybe is '1','11' or '1','2','3','4', Thank u anyway!

Comment: you need to have the right number of parameters in your sqlite text. 

`SELECT * FROM CoachService WHERE shop_id in (?, ?, ?) and brand_id = ?`

will work with 

`briteDatabase.createQuery(CoachService.TABLE_NAME, CoachService.GETBYBRANDIDANDSHOPS,  "1","5","11","2");`


variable amounts of bind parameters is not possible. You'll have to create the query manually in code and add the number of parameters you need.